# Show that the function $f$ has pole of order 1

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

**Problem:**
*Show that the holomorphic function $f$,*
$$\frac{z-\pi}{(e^{iz}+1)^2}:D'(\pi;2\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
*has a pole of order 1 at the point $\pi$.*

This might be really simple but I cannot show that this has pole of order 1 but rather pole order 2, since the denominater is raised to the power of 2? Or am I wrong? When trying to show that it has a pole of order 1 I end with 0/0 but maybe this is sufficient and that 0/0 can be 1 if we compute the limit for $z\rightarrow\pi$?

I hope someone can clear this up for me. Notice that this is not homework. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of holomorphic functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider computing $\lim\limits_{z\to\pi}(z-\pi)f(z)$. Basically the denominator "acts" like $(z-\pi)^2$, so the numerator partially "cancels" one of those factors.

Comment: Ahh didn't see that you edited your comment. Ok this makes sence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the numerator at $\pi$ is $1$, whereas the order of the denominator at $\pi$ is $2$. Therefore, the order of your function at $\pi$ is $-1(=1-2)$. In other words, your function has a simple pole at $\pi$.

Comment: Ahh nice one, so just to make sure. If it was $\frac{(z-\pi)^2}{(e^{\pi i}+1)^3}$ I could use the same argument to say that it has pole of order 1?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$(z-\pi)\frac{z-\pi}{(e^{iz}+1)^2}=\frac{1}{\Big(\frac{e^{iz}+1}{z-\pi}\Big)^2}$$
Let $f(z)=e^{iz}$. Notice that $f(\pi)=-1$. Then
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\pi}\frac{e^{iz}+1}{z-\pi}=\lim_{z\rightarrow\pi}\frac{f(z)-f(\pi)}{z-\pi}=f'(\pi)=-i$$

Hence
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\pi}(z-\pi)\frac{z-\pi}{(e^{iz}+1)^2}=-1$$
From this one may conclude that $f$ has a pole of order one and the residue at $z=\pi$ is $-1$.